# graphviz : dynamically creation of node

Tags: graphviz

i m writing a program such that it requires no of nodes to be control by some variable.
is there any way by which we can draw nodes dynamically if no, of nodes is not decided while writing a code?

Comment: do you want to dynamically add new nodes to an existing graph ? Or is the actual number known when you launch the program ? (if so, aaron's answer is sufficient...).

Answer (score 2):

Write your program in such a way that it accepts a parameter and tell graphviz to create as many nodes as the parameter says.